# creating a table in mysql for events

Tags: mysql, database

I need to create a data base of star gazing events that can be queried by the user entering their location and the date to get results,
The idea is that certain constellations can only be seen in northern hemisphere towns on certain months, I think I can connect them by having a table of events with hemisphere field and a months_viewable field. Also a locations table with a hemisphere field that can link with the events table. 
I am currently planing the following tables,

```
 event table ( event id, event_name, event_type, event_description,       event_month, hemisphere )

 Location table ( local_id, city, country, hemisphere )
```

this would need the event_month field to hold multiple months, is this possible or is there a more suitable way to complete this?
I thought if this would work I could simply then query it using a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM event inner join location
on event.event.hemispher = location.hemispher
WHERE city LIKE (city entered)
AND month LIKE (month entered)
```

Comment: Do these events adhere to strict "month" timelines?  Or would a "start date" and "end date" be more applicable?  If you do want to store "months" then it seems more reasonable to have a table of months and a many-to--many relationship between "events" and "months".

Comment: These events can span several months, ie a certain constellation will be viewable over several months, If I was create a table of months how would  this be referenced on the event table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of options here...

**1.** *If* the data can be granular enough then you'd get more accuracy from a "start date" and an "end date" for the events.  Something like this:

```
event
----------
id,
name,
type,
description,
start_date,
end_date
hemisphere
```

This would allow you to perform date math in queries (or in application code), which may be slightly more complex (but could be easily encapsulated) though would produce more accurate results.

*However*, if the data is *not* that granular and "months" are as specific as it gets...

**2.** Create a "month" table and connect it to the "event" table via a many-to-many relationship.  Something like this:

```
event
----------
id,
name,
type,
description,
hemisphere

month
----------
id
name

event_month
----------
event_id
month_id
```

This separates the *occurrence* of the event from the *event* itself.  If you're ever in a situation where an event *changes* from one month to the next, you can put that data in the `event_month` table.  But more importantly, this allows multiple events to connect to multiple months.

Comment: Thanks David, Yeah the events I will be working with are viewable for set months each year, For example if I have an event that can be seen for 3 months in a row, Would the event_month table simply have several month_id's connected with one event_id, is that possible ?

Comment: @ConorMackel: It's not only possible, it's the reason that table exists.  You'd have one event record with multiple event_month records.

Comment: ok, just so I can get my head around this, would I then have rows in this event_month like so eg (representing an event that is viewable in both month 1 & 2 )          --event_id- 1 , month_id- 1 then event_id 1 month_id 2,    so there would be multiple rows with the same event_id and multiple rows with the same month_id in theory,  Would you have an example query on this proposed set up

Comment: @ConorMackel: That's the gist of it, sure.  The "event" is something like "Ursa Major Visible" and the "event month" is a combined record of something like "Ursa Major Visible in April".  A `SELECT` might look like: `SELECT * FROM event INNER JOIN event_month ON event.id = event_month.event_id INNER JOIN month ON event_month.month_id = month.id`  This would yield a cartesian product of the three tables, duplicating across records as necessary.